# How do I call an implemented interface function

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have a "Page" that implement my own "Permission" interface.

```
public interface PagePermissions{
      Dictionary<string, Permission> readPermissions();
}


public partial class myWebPage: System.Web.UI.Page, PagePermissions
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     Dictionary<string, Permission> PagePermissions.readPermissions()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Permission> results = new Dictionary<string, Permission>();
        return results;
    }
}
```

In my master page, I get a reference to the current Page object.

```
  Page myPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

But I can't call my function ReadPermission because it's not recognizing it:

```
  myPage.readPermissions();
```

How do I call my implemented function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `myPage` to `PagePermissions`.

```
PagePermissions myPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as PagePermissions;
myPage.readPermissions();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting `myPage` to your interface.

```
PagePermissions myPagePermissions = (PagePermissions)myPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using explicit implementation of the interface function? Think about changing the code line

```
Dictionary<string, Permission> PagePermissions.readPermissions()
{
```

to

```
public Dictionary<string, Permission> readPermissions()
{
```

Comment: It will still need to be cast to his interface, `PagePermissions` to access the members--so there's no real difference.

Comment: Wrong. Implicitly implemented interface methods are part of the class's public interface. No need to cast in order to call the function then.